# NSOperation not being fully deallocated? Live Bytes not less than Overall Bytes in Allocations Utility despite operations completing

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, concurrency, nsoperation, grand-central-dispatch

I'm running a large number of `NSOperation` tasks and my application is using a great deal of memory. While it should use quite a bit, it's using magnitudes more than it should, and I'm thinking, from Instruments, that it's because the `NSOperation` objects aren't being fully deallocated. The code for my `NSOperation` subclass is as such:

```
- (id)initFromNode:(BKObject *)sender withNumber:(NSNumber *)number; {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _number = [number retain];
    _sender = [sender retain];
  }
  return self;
}
- (void)main {
  [_sender go:_number];
}
- (void)dealloc {
  [_number release];
  _number = nil;
  [_sender release];
  _sender = nil;
  [super dealloc];
}
```

My suspicions are as such because in Instruments, when I use the Allocations utility, it shows enormous amounts of data for my `_NSOperationInternal` and also my subclasses of `NSOperation`, but the Live Bytes number is always equal to the Overall Bytes number. I've also checked with the Leaks utility, which never finds any memory leaks. I'm careful about releasing any operation objects after adding them to the queue.

I also stuck in a completion block to test it out if it actually finishes, and I can confirm that at least some of them do. Confirming all of them would be more work, and the live data in Instruments should go down a bit, even if only, say 10% of them, were finishing.

I'm at a loss. Let me know if any of my understanding of what I'm doing is off or if more code would be helpful. Do you know what might be going on that this is using more memory than it should?

Comment: Are you using garbage collection? Setting the instance variables to `nil` looks like it. If however you're using it, `-dealloc` won't ever get called.

Comment: No, not using garbage collection. I set to nil because that helps debug other memory issues sometimes.

Comment: I don't think setting it to `nil` ever helps. What it does is hiding bugs, because `[nil something]` is valid whereas `[deallocatedObject something]` leads usually to a crash. However, there is some contraversy around this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug this, try to see if `-dealloc` gets even called. The simplest way to do this is to use an `NSLog`, the correct way would be a breakpoint.

My guesses are:

- You're not correctly releasing the `NSOperations`.
- or you've got retain cycles.
- Some objects *in* your `NSOperation` don't get released, try adding an autorelease pool around your main method.

Comment: Yes, `-dealloc` gets called. I checked with a breakpoint. I'm pretty sure I'm releasing properly, but what should I look for with retain cycles?

Comment: A retain cycle for example is if your `NSOperation` retains the `BKObject` and vice-versa.

Comment: The `BKObject` is the one that creates the operation, but that method literally just creates it (only as a local variable), adds it to the queue, then releases it.

Comment: I've added another suggestion.

Comment: Truth be told, it's actually a bit more complicated than just one `NSOperation` subclass, and so I've been adding some autorelease pools here and there and it seems to be getting better...definitely still accumulating, but it could be for proper reasons now. Will explore further. Thanks.